# Is it possible requests doesn't work well to scrape a website (even with timeout etc.)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I wanted to scrape some Goodreads pages and my code works. However, I use the `requests` library and I noticed that sometimes when I run the code I get an error, the same one, almost every time at a different request.

What I mean by that is when I use these functions to go through the website pages and get books' editions information by giving an input some ISBNs:

```
def get_editions_urls(ed_details):
    # Unpack the tuple with the informations about the editions
    url, ed_num, isbn = ed_details

    # Navigate to all pages for books with more than 100 editions
    for page in range((ed_num // 100) + 1):
        r = requests.get(url, params={
            'page': str(page + 1),
            'per_page': '100',
            #'filter_by_format': 'Paperback',
            'utf8': "%E2%9C%93"})

        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')

        # Find all elements for the editions of the book
        editions = soup.find_all("div", class_="editionData")

        with open(f"urls_files/{isbn}_urls.txt", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            for book in editions:
                if item := book.find("a", class_="bookTitle"):
                        if language := book.find_all("div", class_="dataValue")[-2].text:
                            fp.write(f"https://www.goodreads.com{item['href']}\n" + f"language: {language}\n"
                                    )

        # Let some time to the goodreads server between the requests
        time.sleep(3)
```

In the loop for book in editions every time the code stops at different books- sometimes the first one, sometimes after five, etc. I tried to change `time.sleep` and move it but nothing. The error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` but I put the conditions fo this very reason (sometimes the cycle works for all the books in my list). It doesn't seem to me that the website code changes, so...is it possible the `request` library is weak at this point and if so, what can I use to replace it?

Comment: Maybe the page presents a captcha if it detects strange movement and your code fails.

Comment: What would "weak" even mean in this context? If "doesn't emulate a browser" is weak, then yes, it's weak. If "widely buggy" is weak, then no, it's not weak.

Comment: that's interesting...how can I work around that? When navigating the website manually, this doesn't happen (maybe I'm not quick enough)

Comment: Weak in the sense that it doesn't work well...sorry English is not my first language. I heard a lot about selenium and was wondering if that was a better option or if it's the same.

Comment: When you're "navigating the website manually", there's a ton that goes on behind the scenes -- javascript gets run, f/e, and the server can look for things that javascript is responsible for doing; it can also compare the request headers you're getting to those that come from real browsers.

Comment: Selenium is a better option _if your problem is that the web site is trying to detect whether the client is a real browser_ and cut off clients that aren't. But knowing if that's the case requires insider knowledge of how Goodreads does their system administration.

Comment: BTW, are you aware that https://www.goodreads.com/api exists? Trying to pretend to be a real customer using a conventional browser is only a thing you need to do in the first place if you aren't using an API _intended_ to allow 3rd-party programmatic access.

Comment: (the other thing is that a real browser _that isn't used by a human in normal browser-y ways_ can be detected too, so it's not like selenium is immune to detection; it's closer to the real thing because it controls a browser, but the fact that that browser is being controlled by machine and doesn't have a set of fonts / cached content / cookies / etc. that a real human will is still detectable).

Comment: They don't give out access tokens anymore. That's why I'm trying to scrape it

Comment: Anyhow -- there's only one `.find()` in that code, so you could add a `if book is None: continue` on a line before it to skip any `None` entries in `editions`.

Comment: _Hostile_ scraping is a cat-and-mouse game: You're trying to figure out how to evade their detection measures, they're trying to figure out how to detect you. That's generally not a business Stack Overflow wants to be in: Any answer we gave about "how to evade GoodReads detection" would work only until someone from Goodreads sees it and fixes their detection, so allowing those questions doesn't help us achieve our purpose of building a long-lasting learning resource.

Comment: ...and honestly, `requests` not being a good tool for hostile scraping doesn't have much bearing on whether it's a good tool _in general_.

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible the request library is weak at this point and if so,
> what can I use to replace it?

No, but *your* code is weak.
You are not checking for the **HTTP status code**. It should be 200. If you get anything else, then abort, dump the HTML to a log or text file, and analyze the contents.

This is what you should be doing: **inspect the response**, that is the HTTP status code, and the HTML output from the web server.

The error is that you are trying to parse a response that most likely isn't there. Your script may receive a HTTP/403 page or similar. You need more validation in your code.